# How to hide/ unhide choices based upon a choice selected in the same question

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I am currently making use of the following code which helps me in hiding and displaying the choices. But I am unable to hide and unselect them if choice 1 is unchecked.

[image]

```
var x= jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" input[choiceid=2]").closest("li").hide();

var y = jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" input[choiceid=3]").closest("li").hide();



this.questionclick = function(event, element) {

    var selectedChoice = this.getSelectedChoices()



    console.log(selectedChoice) //use this to get the value of the choice when you want the textbox to appear

    if (selectedChoice == "1") {

      x.show();

y.show();

alert(selectedChoice);

    }

    else if (selectedChoice == "2") {

      //x.hide();

//y.hide();

alert(selectedChoice+"Else if");

    }

else{

x.hide();

y.hide();

alert(selectedChoice+"Else ");

}

  }
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: show html code as well.

Comment: Possibly offtopic: `jQuery("#"+this.questionId+" input[choiceid=2]")` should be written as `jQuery(this).find("input[choiceid=2]")` or `jQuery("input[choiceid=2]"), this)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not contain html that you are using. Here is a small demo I have created to demonstrate the `grouped checkboxes` and `binding` on `click event` with them. Play and do changes as per your need.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/grouped-checkboxes-binding-onclick-function

`this` keyword inside the function refers to the checkbox clicked. you can further checks as you do on normal html checkbox element. e.g `this.checked`means `document.getElementById("myCheck").checked` to check if checkbox is checked or not.

HTML

```
<div class="question">
  <h2 class="q-1">Click to write the Question text</h2>
</div>
<ul class="options-list" id="options-list">
  <li>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="q1-opt1" name="q1['opt1']">
    Click to write choice 1
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="q1-opt2" name="q1['opt2']">
    Click to write choice 2
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="q1-opt3" name="q1['opt3']">
    Click to write choice 3
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="q1-opt4" name="q1['opt4']">
    Click to write choice 4
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.options-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.options-list li label {
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.options-list li label:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
.options-list li label > input {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
(function() {
  // get questions that you want to disable enable
  var q1opt1 = document.getElementById("q1-opt2");
  var q1opt2 = document.getElementById("q1-opt3");

  // get list wrapping element of all checkboxes
  var el = document.getElementById('options-list');
  // get all checkboxes inside wrapping element
  var options = el.getElementsByTagName('input');
  // assign a function each checkbox on click
  for( var i=0, len=options.length; i<len; i++ ) {
    if ( options[i].type === 'checkbox' ) {
        options[i].onclick = function(e) {
          // if checkbox id is q1-opt1
          // and is checked is checking if this is selected.
          // checkbox is hidden with css
          // play with the code
          if ( this.id == 'q1-opt1' && this.checked ) {
            q1opt1.parentElement.style.display = "none";
            q1opt2.parentElement.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            q1opt1.parentElement.style.display = "block";
            q1opt2.parentElement.style.display = "block";
          }
        }
    }
  }
})();
```